# "new" inside concrete type projection is only called once

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've simple Linq2Sql query:

```
var result = from t in MyContext.MyItems
             select new MyViewModelClass()
             {
                 FirstProperty = t,
                 SecondProperty = new SomeLinq2SqlEntity()
             }
```

The problem is that it seems that `new SomeLinq2SqlEntity()` is executed only once for the sequence, so all instances of `MyViewModelClass` in result of the query share the link to one object.

**Update**: Here is how I quickly check it:

```
result[0].SecondProperty.MyField = 10;
```

Using debugger I can check that `MyField` was set to `10` in all instances.

When I replace LINQ query with foreach, it works as expected:

```
  var result = from t in MyContext.MyItems select t;
  var list = new List<MyViewModelClass>();
  foreach (var item in result)
  {
      list.add(new MyViewModelClass()
             {
                 FirstProperty = item,
                 SecondProperty = new SomeLinq2SqlEntity()
             });       
  }
```

**I haven't found the root of the problem, but the post marked as asnwer provides good workaround. Check this asnwer for the detailed description: ["new" inside concrete type projection is only called once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899825/new-inside-concrete-type-projection-is-only-called-once/6902134#6902134)**

Comment: you say it _seems_ the instantiation is only executed once. How have you verified this? have you tryed chaning one property to see the value reflected in all projected objects or does it seem to be the case because only one object is later persistent or something else?

Comment: I've added quick test in "update" section.

Comment: This is definitely something to do with linq to sql: a similar example entirely in linq to objects `var v = "abc".Select(c => new ObjectContainer() { o = new SomeClass() });` results in the `SomeClass` ctor being called the expected **three** times

Comment: What happens if you don't have the semi-colon at the end (`;`) of the new expression?

Comment: That was my mistake when I writed code for the question, I've removed the semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using adding the `SomeLinq2SqlEntity` object with linq to objects?

```
var result = (from t in MyContext.MyItems
             select new
             {
                 FirstProperty = t
             })
             .AsEnumerable() 
             .Select(t => new MyViewModelClass()
             {
                 FirstProperty = t.FirstProperty ,
                 SecondProperty = new SomeLinq2SqlEntity();
             });
```

Comment: Thanks! Conceptually this seems to be the same as `foreach` solution, I was completely sure that my first attempt will behave the same. I don't understand why it doesn't work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It probably has something to do with weird `IQueryable` implementation of your provider.
Aducci's answer extracts data from database with `AsEnumerable()` call and performs the query on that set, which is different from performing it through `IQueryable`.

For example `IQueryable` builds the `ExpressionTree` which it later parses according to the concrete provider (i.e. executing shared code once for optimization), while IEnumerable accepts `Func` and performs it as you would expect.

You can read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ff963710

Comment: I'm using default LINQ2SQL MS SQL provider on .NET 4.0. Is this a (wellknown) bug?

Comment: Not sure, but afaik Linq2Sql is a bit outdated and discontinued, so you'd probably be better off using Entity Framework.

Comment: It is still supported (but it seems doesn't get any new features). The application in question was started a long time ago when EF was not so good as today.